# Variable affected by type conversion

Tags: c, uint32

I have always thought that when a variable is typecast, a copy of it results and any changes affect that temporary variable. But, the screenshot below indicates otherwise.  Apparently, the original variable is what changes. Why? I am curious because I have never seen anything similar.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Not always, but often, a type cast just **re-interprets** the bits that make up a certain type as the same bits the make up another type. But a cast can also cause a conversion, e.g. `(int)myFloat`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis no, a cast *never* does that. You can use it to obtain a type-punned pointer and reinterpret with that in some cases though.

Comment: @Quentin: then what does the following cast do: `int a = -17; unsigned int b = (unsigned int)a;`. I would call that re-interpretation.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis see [the second bullet point here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_conversions). Everything is defined in terms of the represented value, not of the representation. An implementation might, for example, use sign-magnitude representation for negative integers, whose bits would not match these of the unsigned representation of that same number after the modulo.

Comment: @Quentin: that describes conversions, not casts.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis A cast is an operator which performs a conversion

Comment: re-interpretation would be `unsigned int b = *(unsigned int *)&a;`  , which may give a different value for `b` than the above code

Comment: @RudyVelthuis fair doubt. It looks like there's an error on cppreference on the "cast operator" page, so I'll quote the standard ([N1570, 6.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3)): "This subclause specifies the result required from [an] implicit conversion , as well as those that  result  from  a  cast  operation  (an explicit  conversion)." -- then follows the bullet list I linked above ([6.3.1.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3)).

Answer (score 4):

`sprintf` nul-terminates the string it outputs into the provided buffer. As the `%010lu` format specifier requests a number padded to be at least 10 digits long, you are consistently overflowing `crc_buf` and triggering UB. In your specific case, the least significant byte of `crc` gets trampled.

Make `crc_buf` 11 characters or more, and use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` to catch this class of errors. For maximal portability, you could also use the `PRIu32` format macro instead of casting:

```
snprintf(crc_buf, sizeof crc_buf, "%10" PRIu32, crc);
```